I need to select the adding radio button by default in my blazor app`
I cannot set the Adding radio button to be selected by default when the page loads
The actual radio button is not getting selected, but the mode is set to scanning and the UI is green to indicate that the mode is set
My requirement is that the actual button needs to be selected when initialized
This is my card that includes the radio button
 <div style="position:sticky">
     <ParrotInformationExpander ButtonText="Scanner Information">
         <div style="max-height:250px; overflow-y:auto;">
             <ol>
                 <li>Start scanning barcodes.</li>
                 <li>Ensure all items related to the order are scanned off the vehicle.</li> 
                 <li>Click on a card to view parcels scanned and not scanned.</li>  
                 <li>Once all items are scanned off the vehicle, the complete button will be activated.</li> 
             </ol>
         </div>
     </ParrotInformationExpander>

     <div class="mb-3">
         <label for="barcodeInput" class="form-label">Barcode:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" @onkeyup="OnKeyUpAsync" @bind-value="VM.BarcodeInput" @bind-value:event="oninput" @ref="_textboxRef" placeholder="Scan or enter a barcode." />

     </div>

     <div class="p-card-header">
         <ParrotRadioGroup GroupName="AddAndRemoveBtns" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
             <div class="form-check d-inline-block m-3">
                 <ParrotRadioInput @bind-Value="VM.IsAdding" @onclick="@(e => ChangeScanMode(ScanningMode.Adding))" Id="btnradio1" Class="form-check-input" autocomplete="off">
                     <label class="btn btn-outline-success w-100" for="btnradio1">Add</label>
                 </ParrotRadioInput>
             </div>
             <div class="form-check d-inline-block m-3">
                 <ParrotRadioInput @bind-Value="VM.IsRemoving" @onclick="@(e => ChangeScanMode(ScanningMode.Removing))" Id="btnradio2" Class="form-check-input" autocomplete="off">
                     <label class="btn btn-outline-danger w-100" for="btnradio2">Remove</label>
                 </ParrotRadioInput>
             </div>
         </ParrotRadioGroup>

         <div class="row m-2 ">
             <div class="col-12 mb-1 p-1">
                 <ParrotActionButton Class="btn p-btn-success w-100" Id="CompleteScanOff" IsDisabled="@VM.CompleteBtnDisabled">Complete</ParrotActionButton>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

 </div> 

Here is how I am trying to change it from my razor.cs file
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
     await base.OnInitializedAsync();
     VM.FocusOnTextbox = true;
     VM.CurrentScanningMode = ScanningMode.Adding; 
     _inputTimer = new EventTimer(2000) { AutoReset = false };
     _inputTimer.Elapsed += OnInputTimerElapsed;
     VM.BusyStateHasChanged += StateHasChanged;
     VM.OnResultRaised += ShowNotification;
     VM.Setup();
 }

 #endregion Protected Methods

 #region Private Methods

 /// <summary>
 /// Changes the scanning mode.
 /// </summary>
 private void ChangeScanMode(ScanningMode mode)
 {
     if (mode == ScanningMode.Adding)
     {
         VM.IsAdding = true;
         VM.IsRemoving = false;
     }
     else
     {
         VM.IsRemoving = true;
         VM.IsAdding = false;
     }
     VM.CurrentScanningMode = mode;
     StateHasChanged();
 } 

here is the setup method
 public void Setup()
{
    try
    {
        SetAsBusy("Loading");
        IsAdding = true;
        IsRemoving = false;
        SelectedReason = new RedeliveryReasonModel();
        if (Reasons.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            GetRedeliveryReasonAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var sr = new SuccessResultBuilder();
        sr = sr.Invalid().WithError(ex);
        EmitResult(sr);
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        SetAsIdle();
    }
} 


You should perhaps not have separate bools that remember a value independently of scanning mode.. Just write properties that use the value of ScanningMode to determine if the boolyness of IsAdding/IsRemoving is true or false e.g. public bool IsAdding { get => CurrentScanningMode  == ScanningMode.Adding; set => CurrentScanningMode = value ? ScanningMode.Adding : ScanningMode.Removing } }. Try not to write code where multiple different things store the same state, because then you have the headache of keeping them all in sync. Have one source of truth

What's a ParrotRadioGroup and a ParrotRadioInput?

Our custom components

In OnInitializedAsync() do not set the scanning mode directly; your method that keeps your disparate sources of truth in sync is private void ChangeScanMode(ScanningMode mode) - call this method when you want to change the scanning mode. If you directly set VM.CurrentScanningMode, then your truths have gone out of sync; the radio button is binded to IsAdding, but you directly set Mode = Removing, the mode is now removal but the IsAdding is still true, and your radio button doesn't change. Do you understand (now) what I mean about having a single source of truth?

I have no knowledge of how ParrotRadioGroup and ParrotRadioInput are coded, so I'm assuming they're similar to the standard Blazor controls.  I'm also assuming ScanningMode is an enum.  Based on these guesses, you should probably be doing something like this.  Note the binding on the group component, not on the individual buttons.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div>
    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="_model.CurrentScanningMode">
        @foreach (var option in _options)
        {
            <div>
                <InputRadio Value="option" /> @option
            </div>
        }
    </InputRadioGroup>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>@_model.CurrentScanningMode</pre>
</div>
@code{
    private Model _model = new() { CurrentScanningMode= ScanningMode.Removing };
    private List<ScanningMode> _options = new() { ScanningMode.Adding, ScanningMode.Removing };

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _model.CurrentScanningMode = ScanningMode.Adding;
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public ScanningMode CurrentScanningMode { get; set; }
    }

    public enum ScanningMode
    {
        Adding,
        Removing
    }
}

I may have not fully understood the context and oversimplified this.
